# Is it ok to copy answer from Twitter post?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently I asked the question [How to add more than one beacon in a single region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393612/how-to-add-1-beacons-in-single-region). I shared this question on Twitter with `Estimote` tag and their engineer gave me an answer.

So now I want to post this tweet as an answer. Is it OK to post it?

Comment: When you post the tweet, you should link to the actual tweet. "From Twitter" doesn't count as proper attribution.

Comment: Ask the person who wrote it??

Comment: And if the engineer in question wants to write his own answer, let him do so and accept it.

Comment: @MD: So ask him on Twitter? Not every single conversation regarding software development needs to take place on Stack Overflow. Indeed, as you can see, you have your answer now direct from the horse's mouth. This question was pointless.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you have gotten an answer, no matter where you got it from, you are most definitely allowed to answer your own question. I would however not necessarily just copy and paste a tweet. Try to expand on it a little, put it in a format suitable for the site, add whatever you figured out yourself.

And as always, provide proper attribution.

Comment: "_Try to expand on it a little_" definitely.  Especially since I seriously doubt that a 140 character answer would be complete.

Comment: @ryanyuyu well, it _was_ suitable for most questions 6 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Always link to the original URL and cite *why* you found it useful and how you implemented it specific to your question.

Generally you're not supposed to do a full quotation of the source though this may be difficult if not outright impossible in some scenarios which is why it is critical to always link back to the source.

If you *must* quote the entire post (due to it's brevity) I would add *how* you came across finding the answer (e.g. a search engine query, what operators, etc) so others encountering the same problem will understand how *you* managed to find the answer.

Comment: Why is "how you came across finding the answer" something that  needs to be included in the answer?

Comment: The tweet doesnt exist in a vaccum. The tweeter might be a useful community member that can answer more questions. Further the tweet is likely to be in a chain of tweets that can shed more like to it. Furthermore, its just polite to acknowledge as source.

Comment: @Shayne Citing the source wasn't the bit that I was questioning. It was the advice to state what search engine terms are used etc. That seems like irrelevant noise to me.

Comment: @MartinSmith How is giving insight in to *how* you came across an answer *not* useful especially if that answer is/was difficult to find?

Comment: It may or may not be useful but it is off topic. The goal of SO is to answer programming questions not to give inline mini tutorials on search engine technique.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am completely agree with you.

Comment: @MartinSmith Giving insight in to the methods used to find difficult to find answers is *never* off-topic; helping people discover *how* to find answers is *never* off-topic; not sure why you lack that insight however thankfully not everyone thinks like you.